# Javascript / Form

Tags: javascript, mysql, forms, loops

I'm working on a project that will use loops to add many forms into a mysql database. In the javascript section i can not get the var i to work inside the function updatesum(). Can someone help me out?

I'm tryin to aviod having to do this:

```
document.form1.total.value = (document.form1.number1.value -0) + (document.form1.number2.value -0);
document.form2.total.value = (document.form2.number1.value -0) + (document.form2.number2.value -0);
...........
document.form48.total.value = (document.form48.number1.value -0) + (document.form48.number2.value -0);
document.form49.total.value = (document.form49.number1.value -0) + (document.form49.number2.value -0);
```

There will be about 12 other calculations that will have to take place.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function updatesum() {

for(var i=0; i < 50; i++)
        { 
    document.form[i].total.value = (document.form[i].number1.value -0) + (document.form[i].number2.value -0);
            }
        }
    //-->
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>#</td>
        <td>NUMBER</td>
    </tr>
<? 
$x=1;



while($x <= 50) 
    { ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <? echo $x; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form name="form<? echo $x;?>" >
                    <table border="1">
                        <tr>
                            <td>NUMBER1</td>
                            <td>NUMBER2</td>
                            <td>TOTAL</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input name="number1" size="2" onChange="updatesum()" /></td>
                            <td><input name="number2" size="2" onChange="updatesum()" /></td>
                            <td><input name="total"  size="3" readonly style="border:0px;"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>

    <? $x++; } ?>
</table>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well your making 49 functions that have the same name... And why do you have a function in a loop...

Comment: ^^^^ actually, the OP is making only one function, as the first 48 are overwritten by the last one ?

Comment: I thought it would just make 49 of them but only one would work... but thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your loop, you're defining a function. This is different from calling/invoking a function.

Try

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--

function updatesum() {
   document.form[i].total.value = (document.form[i].number1.value -0) + (document.form[i].number2.value -0);
}

for(var i=0; i < 50; i++) {
   updatesum();
}

//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the function inside the form like that.
I suggest defining the function outside the loop and calling it inside the loop:

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/3zjb6/)**

```
function updatesum() {
    var forms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
    for (var v = 0; v < 50; v++) {
         var input = forms[v].getElementsByTagName("input");
        input[2].value = eval(input[0].value) + eval(input[1].value);
    }
}
```

If you explain what you want with that code we can help you more. In your html you call the function also, and I cannot predict what you expect it to do...

Comment: I'm trying to avoid doing this
<script type="text/javascript">

    function updatesum() {
        document.form1.total.value = (document.form1.number1.value -0) + (document.form1.number2.value -0);
        document.form2.total.value = (document.form2.number1.value -0) + (document.form2.number2.value -0);
        document.form3.total.value = (document.form3.number1.value -0) + (document.form3.number2.value -0);
        document.form4.total.value = (document.form4.number1.value -0) + (document.form4.number2.value -0);
    }
</script>

Comment: the var $x from the form could be as high as 60 and there will be about 12 different calulations i'm trying to make for each $x

Comment: @user2578177, just updated my answer. Check the live demo there also.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the function every time your loop runs. What you want to do is first define your function outside of the loop. Then call it with each loop iteration. You will also want to pass the index (ie. i) to the function.

Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function updatesum(i) {
        document.form[i].total.value = (document.form[i].number1.value -0) + (document.form[i].number2.value -0);
    }

    for(var i=0; i < 50; i++) {
            updatesum(i); 
    }

</script>
```

Let us know how it worked for you.